# How to get JSON Array without object key using retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I'm having trouble loading want to retrieve url data from JSON below

```
{
     "status": "success",
     "message": "This is a message",
     "item":{
         "id":"1",
         "video":{
             "url" : [
                 "https://url1.com",
                 "https://url1.com",
                 "https://url1.com"
             ]
          }
     }
}
```

ResponseData

```
public class ResponseData {

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("item")
    private Item item;

    //Getters
}
```

Item

```
public class Item {
   
   @SerializedName("id")
   private String id;
   @SerializedName("video")
   private Video video;
   
   //Getters
}
```

Video

```
public class Video { 

   @SerializedName("url")
   private List<String> urlList;
   
   //Getters
}
```

What should I do after this to get each URL and apply it in Retrofit onResponse?

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseData> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseData> response) {
     if (response.isSuccessful()) {
         ResponseData resp = response.body();

         //For the call I want results like the method below
         DataFromServer d = new DataFromServer();
         d.url = resp.getItem().getVideo().getUrlList().getUrl1(); // I want it like this
     }
 }
```

Comment: What exactly you want? You are getting the response, do you want to return the urls?

Comment: I want to get the url one by one, but the getUrlList() method in Video Class cannot be called because it is a List data type, whereas I want to get that method and then call it with the getUrl1() method to call it in retrofit response

Comment: assuming data is parsed properly then you can use `getUrlList().get(1);`

Comment: Not getting you properly, but If you want each url one by one then use **for loop** and use index no. Like this `getUrlList().get(i);` here **i** indicate index no.

Comment: I tried this getUrlList().get(i);  But the value obtained is always null

Comment: can you try printing the getUrlList() so we know whether there are urls in it or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    resp.getItem().getVideo().getUrlList().forEach((url) -> {
       Log.i("url", url) // you can get each url here
     }
    );
```

you are basically getting a list from server.

you don't need keys to access them. you can store them in list and also do

list.get(0) - for first url

list.get(1) - for second url

and so on.

Comment: `forEach` is Kotlin method, OPs code is in Java, above won't compile/build

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-foreach-method-in-java/

@snachmsm